# "Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body" error when building Minecraft Forge 1.17.1 MDK

Tags: java, maven, gradle, minecraft-forge

Error report:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'forge-1.17.1-37.0.53-mdk'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':_compileJava_1'.
   > Could not download icu4j-66.1.jar (com.ibm.icu:icu4j:66.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://maven.minecraftforge.net/com/ibm/icu/icu4j/66.1/icu4j-66.1.jar'.
         > Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 12,935,630; received: 6,041,008)
   > Could not download fastutil-8.2.1.jar (it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:8.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://maven.minecraftforge.net/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/8.2.1/fastutil-8.2.1.jar'.
         > Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 18,800,417; received: 3,661,296)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I have tried many times and this error always occurs.

Minecraft version:1.17.1
MinecraftForge version:1.17.1-37.0.53
Java version:1.16

Do I need to check my internet connection? Or there's something wrong with the maven`https://maven.minecraftforge.net`? (I added a mirror `https://lss233.littleservice.cn/repositories/minecraft` but didn't solve the problem)

Please help me!

[build.gradle](https://cl1p.net/uqzubzfigwwdu) here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem might be occurring due to one or more problems mentioned below:-

1. Server-Side issues: Many times, the server becomes unresponsive and either sends less data or no data at all. Try after 4-5 hours. Sometimes, it can even take a day!
2. "build.gradle" file is bugged: If you've not modified your build.gradle file at any time, then it can't be the/a reason.

Try navigating into your MDK folder and run `gradlew eclipse` command.
Please post your build.gradle file correctly, it isn't opening :).

Comment: Thanks. I changed the mirror and it works.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark this answer as accepted, so it may help others :)